# How can I combine jQuery Validate with this ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I have an ajax post which submits nicely, but I need to combine it with jQuery Validate before I submit and I just can't make it work.

I have tried submitting the ajax within the submit handler but this makes some of the fields in my form disappear or just do not update my database in some cases.

Using this separately works just fine:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = 'http://example.com';
    var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(){
        $('.pop_up').fadeOut();
      } 
    });

});
```

But the following code doesn't work 100% (just sometimes and some parts). Sometimes it posts with email field being empty and sometimes other fields are wacko.

```
var url = 'http://example.com';
var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();
$('#myform').validate({

rules: {
        emailaddress: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        meeting: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $('input[name=in_12_months]').is(':checked')==false && $('input[name=in_6_months]').is(':checked')==false
                }
            }
        }

},

submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(){
        $('.pop_up').fadeOut(); 
        }         
    });
}
});
```

The validation separated from the Submithandler works, so it won't post unless the required fields are ok.

So how do I combine these to 100% reliable data that posts nicely?

I have several forms in my webpage, should I maybe address the specific form instead of  `submitHandler: function(form)`?

Comment: *"I have tried submitting the ajax within the submit handler but this makes some of the fields in my form disappear or just do not update my database in some cases."* ~  This makes no sense... the `submitHandler` is the only way to do this correctly and millions of people use this plugin without such issues.  Show us a more complete demo including the relevant HTML.

Comment: *"But the following code doesn't work 100% (just sometimes and some parts). Sometimes it posts with email field being empty and sometimes other fields are wacko."*  ~ Please fix your question to better explain everything with sufficient details.  Nobody knows what "other fields are wacko" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
var url = 'http://example.com';
var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();

$('#myform').validate({
    .....
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data, ....
```

You cannot serialize the data outside of the `submitHandler`.   It's not going to work here because the form is empty when `.serialize()` is called.

Put it inside the `submitHandler` while leveraging the `form` argument of the callback function...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    .....
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            ....
```

You'll also probably want to use `.serialize()` instead of `.serializeArray()`.

Read [the `.ajax()` documentation for `data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: Beautiful, Sparky!